# Set properties for InvokeHTTP Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to set some properties before my `InvokeHTTP` processor in NiFi. In fact, I try to use an API and I would like to give HTTP headers with key API.

I can set all properties with a lot of `UpdadeAttribute` but there is two problems :

- I can't start my work on a `UpdadeAttribute`
- All my properties have to be set one time, no more

These properties are in assembly of two keys.

First, I merge the two keys in `merged_keys`

```
${api_key}:${api_secret_key}
```

Second, I encode `merged_keys` in `encoded64_key`.

```
${merged_key:base64Encode()}
```

Then, I write my HTTP header `Authorization` using `encoded64_key`

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ${encoded64_key}'
```

**edit :** I tried to set this configuration in `UpdateAttribute` but I know that isn't a good way so I tried to set it directly in my `InvokeHTTP` and nothing happen.

The part of building HTTP header works perfectly but I don't know how can I do for give this header to my `InvokeHTTP` one time.

Answer (score 2):

Set a property on the InvokeHTTP processor with name `Authorization` and value `Based ${encoded64_key}`. This is the way to attach the header. See the [documentatinos](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/).

> An HTTP client processor which can interact with a configurable HTTP Endpoint. The destination URL and HTTP Method are configurable. **FlowFile attributes are converted to HTTP headers** and the FlowFile contents are included as the body of the request (if the HTTP Method is PUT, POST or PATCH).

FYI with the contents, you should give the contents as a flowfile by using replaceText processor.

Comment: I tried to set ```Authorization``` as u said but nothing happen. Is it possible to do all my manipulations (merge keys, encoding...) in different properties but always in my ```InvokeHTTP```?

Comment: Try `Based ${literal(${api_key}:${api_secret_key}):base64Encode()}` or you have to use updateAttribute processor.

Comment: I can't write ```${...something...:...something...}``` in NiFi. It's a mistake.